# Comparison of two biased random walks on integers

Tags: probability, random-walk

Consider two i.i.d. random sequences $(X_i)$ and $(Y_i)$.
Assume that $$
\begin{aligned}
\Pr[X_i=1]&=0.6 & \Pr[X_i=0]&=0.1 & \Pr[X_i=-1]&=0.3 \\ 
\Pr[Y_i=1]&=0.4 & \Pr[Y_i=0]&=0.4 & \Pr[X_i=-1]&=0.2~.
\end{aligned}$$
Let $S_X(t)=\sum_{i=1}^tX_i$ and $S_Y(t)=\sum_{i=1}^tY_i$.

Then, for all $k>0$ and for all $t>0$, can we show 
$$\Pr[S_X(t)\geq k]\geq \Pr[S_Y(t)\geq k]  \\ 
\text{or} \\
\Pr[S_X(t)\geq k]\leq \Pr[S_Y(t)\geq k] ~?$$

Comment: You should be able to answer one of the questions simply by computing the probabilities for $k=1$.  I assume the initial condition is the same for both, say, $S_X(0)=S_Y(0)=0$.

Comment: >>by computing the probabilities for k=1. I have not understood that. Would you tell me the reason or textbook?

Comment: Try $k=1$ and $t=1$.

Comment: Thanks. I added "for all $t>0$".

Answer (score 1):

No, because for $t=1$ we get $$0.6=\Pr[S_X(1)\geq 1]>\Pr[S_Y(1)\geq 1]=0.4$$ but $$0.7=\Pr[S_X(1)\geq 0]<\Pr[S_Y(1)\geq 0]=0.8,$$
so which way round the inequality goes will depend on $k$. In fact you get a similar problem for every $t\geq 1$ by considering $k=t$ and $k=1-t$.

If the inequalities *did* all go the same way for $t=1$, that would actually imply the general case, since you could then find a coupling of the two sequences such that $X_i\geq Y_i$ for every $i$ (or vice versa).